# Don't Quote Me On This

Tags: lateral-thinking

Consider the following quotes:

> I'm trying to free your mind, Neo. But I can only show you the door. You're the one that has to walk through it.
>   *The Matrix*
>
> A garden is a lovesome thing, God wot!
>     Rose plot,
>     Fringed pool,
>   Fern'd grot—
>   *Thomas Edward Brown*
>
> There is nothing more helpless and irresponsible than a man in the depths of an ether binge.
>   *Hunter S. Thompson*

Which of the following best completes this **ordered sequence** and why?

**A:**

> Terah took his son Abram, his grandson Lot son of Haran, and his daughter-in-law Sarai, 
>   the wife of his son Abram, and together they set out from Ur of the Chaldeans to go to Canaan.
>   *Genesis 11:31*

**B:**

> There is a tide in the affairs of men, Which taken at the flood, leads on to fortune.
>   *William Shakespeare*

**C:**

> We are young, wandering the face of the earth
>   Wondering what our dreams might be worth
>   Learning that we're only immortal for a limited time
>   *Rush*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I notice that the first three

> contain NEO (=ONE), WOT (=TWO) and THERE (=THREE) respectively.

But none of the candidate fourth ones

> contain a word that's an anagram of FOUR. The best I can do is that A has "UR OF" (two words). Perhaps that's the intended answer?

Incidentally, if this or something sufficiently like it is the intention, it might be better

> to say "continues" rather than "completes". I'm pretty sure I remember reading somewhere that there are more numbers after 4.

Comment: Whoa, that was fast, kudos :)

Comment: That, indeed, is it. Anagrams usually encompass single and multiple word re-arrangements. The first three numbers didn't yield and multiple word anagrams that interested me. Your point about further numbers is valid. Congratulations!

Comment: @ABcDexter: The Neo/One thing is kinda famous, and the "wot" in the second one rather jumps out (I can't offhand think of anything else famous with that word in). I think it would have been harder, at least for me, if the first quotation had been about (say) Brian Eno and the second had had a Yorkshireman using the word "owt". (I am not suggesting that that would have been an improvement.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Redwall hares regularly use 'wot'. :P

Comment: Also in #3: ether.

Answer (score 1):

> C

None of the first three

> has a J, K, X, or Z.

A & B

> Have at least one of those. C doesn't.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm looking for an ordered sequence. "What do these have in common" would be too broad.

Comment: @HughMeyers :/ That was the only thing I could find. I'll keep looking!